# Using both DISTINCT and ORDER BY in json_agg

Tags: postgresql, json

I'm trying to get a sorted aggregate of unique values in postgresql. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4556b/23)

The result should be a json array of unique objects, sorted by `index` field. The `value` field can be used as unique key in this case if needed.

The structure and data is similar to this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  index INTEGER,
  value INTEGER,
  tag VARCHAR
);

-- In the real query, this table is the result of a join. 
-- That is the explanation for duplicated rows.
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1, 1, 'a'),
  (1, 1, 'a'),
  (1, 1, 'a'),
  (2, 1, 'a'),
  (3, 2, 'a')
;
```

Getting an aggregate of distinct rows works:

```
SELECT json_agg(DISTINCT test.*) FROM test GROUP BY tag;
```

```
[{"index":1,"value":1,"tag":"a"}, {"index":2,"value":1,"tag":"a"}, {"index":3,"value":2,"tag":"a"}]
```

Order by without distinct also works:

```
SELECT json_agg(test.* ORDER BY index) FROM test GROUP BY tag;
```

```
[{"index":1,"value":1,"tag":"a"}, {"index":1,"value":1,"tag":"a"}, {"index":1,"value":1,"tag":"a"}, {"index":2,"value":1,"tag":"a"}, {"index":3,"value":2,"tag":"a"}]
```

The problem happens if using both:

```
SELECT json_agg(DISTINCT test.* ORDER BY index) FROM test GROUP BY tag;
```

```
ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list Position: 42
```

If I try to add the `ORDER BY` column I get an error, since `json_agg` expects only one value:

```
SELECT json_agg(DISTINCT (SELECT test.index, test.*) ORDER BY index) FROM test GROUP BY tag;
```

```
ERROR: subquery must return only one column Position: 28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM test)
SELECT json_agg(cte.* ORDER BY index) FROM cte GROUP BY tag;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have searched for alternative solutions since making this two steps complicates the final query too much. However, seems that there is no other way than making a subquery with a `DISTINCT` and then an `ORDER BY` in the aggregation like your example.